# Jensen's inequality and $L^p$ norms

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space; in particular, $\mu(X)=1$. The integral form of Jensen's inequality can be phrased in terms of permuting a convex function $\varphi$ (say, with the property that $\varphi(0)=0$) and the $L^1(d\mu)$ norm:

$$\varphi\Big(\|f\|_{L^1(d\mu)}\Big)\leq \|\varphi\circ f\|_{L^1(d\mu)}.$$

My question is: does a similar statement hold for $\|\cdot\|_{L^p(d\mu)}$ norms with $p>1$? More precisely, given a convex function $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(0)=0$ and an exponent $1\leq p\leq \infty$, does there exist a constant $C_p<\infty$ such that

$$\varphi\Big(\|f\|_{L^p(d\mu)}\Big)\leq C_p\|\varphi\circ f\|_{L^p(d\mu)}$$
for every $f\in L^p(d\mu)$?

Thank you.

Comment: You need $\varphi\ge0$ for the $L^1$ result to be true, don't you?

Comment: @Hanche-Olsen: Edited, thanks.

Comment: At least for the functions $x^p$ for $p>1$, Jensen holds over sets of finite measure, so long as you take the average: $(\frac{1}{|A|}\int_A |f|)^p \leq \frac{1}{|A|}\int_A (|f|^p)$. This follows directly from Holder's inequality

Comment: @Sebastian: Right, so the question is whether the estimate holds for more general convex functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g=|f|^p$ and $\psi(t)=\varphi(t^{1/p})^p$. Then the inequality $$\varphi\Big(\|f\|_{L^p(d\mu)}\Big)\leq C_p\|\varphi\circ |f|\|_{L^p(d\mu)} \tag1$$
becomes 
$$\psi\left(\int g\,d\mu\right)\le C_p^p\int (\psi\circ g)\,d\mu \tag2$$
For (2) to be true for arbitrary $g$, we need $\psi$ to be convex to $[0,\infty)$. This can be phrased as a  differential inequality for $\varphi$ which is neither stronger nor weaker than $\varphi''\ge 0$. For example, with $p=2$ my computations show that $\psi''\ge 0$ is equivalent to $$t(\varphi\varphi''+(\varphi')^2)-\varphi\varphi'\ge 0 \tag3$$